# Why cloned repository has not the same set of branches?

Tags: git, github

Git for Windows version 2.6.4.windows.1

In the [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) book I have read the `git clone` creates full copy of repository:

> If you want to get a copy of an existing Git repository – for example,
>   a project you’d like to contribute to – the command you need is `git clone`.
>   If you’re familiar with other VCS systems such as Subversion,
>   you’ll notice that the command is "clone" and not "checkout". This is
>   an important distinction – instead of getting just a working copy, Git
>   receives a full copy of nearly all data that the server has. Every
>   version of every file for the history of the project is pulled down by
>   default when you run `git clone`. In fact, if your server disk gets
>   corrupted, you can often use nearly any of the clones on any client to
>   set the server back to the state it was in when it was cloned (you may
>   lose some server-side hooks and such, but all the versioned data would
>   be there – see Getting Git on a Server for more details).

I cloned some Git repository from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/progit2.git
```

I see the `origin` remote has six branches:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/progit2.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/progit2.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    ch#1.6                 tracked
    ch4-gerrit             tracked
    correction-corrections tracked
    epub-fix               tracked
    fix-quotes             tracked
    master                 tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

But the `git branch` command shows my local copy has only one branch:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git branch` only shows you your local branches.

When you clone a remote repository, all the branches are cloned as well, but only `master` branch is automatically being `checkout` to your working directory.

Use

```
git branch -a
```

to see all branches.
And use

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```

to checkout branches.
If `branch-name` matches remote branch name, it would automatically set it as upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
git branch -a
```

[Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Answer (score 0):

You will have only once branch at a time. At the time of cloning it clones the master branch by default. That's why you it shows master branch for you.

You can change checkout other branch of your repository by using the following command.

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```